# Is the Ruronoi Kenshin movie important to the actual storyline?

Tags: rurouni-kenshin

There is the 1997 animated film also two other animated approximately 50m episodes (I’m not sure what they were called).

Are they important to the actual storyline? Do they cover specific episodes/arcs?